# Make Select2 wider than the input?

Tags: jquery-select2

I have various Select2 dropdowns.  I have a issues where when the input is narrow and the drop down is also very small and hard to read.

[image]

I have tired:

```
.select2-dropdown.select2-dropdown--below {

  min-width: 300px !important;

}
```

Which works great:

[image]

I am wondering if there is a way to have Select2 automatically adjust the width?

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out as I was drafting the question - Its a combo of CSS and Select2 configuration:

**Select2:**

```
  width: 'auto'
  dropdownAutoWidth : true
```

**CSS:**

```
.select2-results__option {

  white-space: nowrap;

}

.select2.select2-container {

  width: 100% !important;

}
```

The `nowrap` was the key.  That forces the option to be full width and then the Select2 config.  My added 100% width was to keep the actual input select full width in the table I have these nested in.